# Highlight and copy text within hyperlink in a pdf

Tags: pdf, preview, copy-paste, url

Say there is a phrase in a pdf file that is a hyperlink: "This is a hyperlink". How can I select/highlight just the text in the middle in order to copy and paste it elsewhere without opening the link? That is, how can I just copy and paste "is a" from the example without triggering the hyperlink to open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to copy just the beginning or the end of the url, you can begin your click and drag to select the text on either side of the active hyperlink.

If you're trying to select text that is in the center of the hyperlink, your best bet may be to right click the hyperlink and choose "copy", then edit the link after you've pasted it elsewhere.